# how to update List<T> variable using where condition

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to update the values of a list object by searching the id from the object . //how can I am trying to update FirstName, LastName with firstname,lastyname from argument of the method to update the collection having id = 2
Here is my code

```
public class personRepo
{
   private List<Persons> _persons;       
   public personRepo()
   {
    _persons = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person  (){Id = 1, FirstName = "AAA", LastName="asds"},
                new Person  (){Id = 2,FirstName = "BBB", LastName = "acasddas"},
                new Person  (){Id = 3, FirstName = "CCC", LastName = "asd" }
                 
            };
   }
    public void UpdatePerson(int id ,firstname,lastname)
        {
             id = 2
             firstname = 'zzz'
             lastname = 'zzzzzz'
        
         //after update the list must be changed into 
    
        {Id = 1, FirstName = "AAA", LastName="asds"},
                {Id = 2,FirstName = "zzz", LastName = "zzzzzz"},
                {Id = 3, FirstName = "CCC", LastName = "asd" }
           
        }
}
```

Comment: What are you stuck on that prevents you from accomplishing the objective you've described?

Comment: You could use `Linq` to filter your search. You can get from our offical [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/filtering-data)